# Solving an integral with a complex component

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to find

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-at} \sin{bt} \ dt
$$

where $a>0$ and $b$ is constant.

I'm familiar with Euler's formula, and also derived the identity

$$
\int e^{(-a+ib)t} \ dt = \frac{(-a-ib)e^{(-a+ib)t}}{a^{2}+b^{2}}
$$

which looked hopeful.

Then applying Euler's formula in the first step,

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-at} \sin{bt} \ dt &= \frac{1}{2i}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-at}\big(e^{ibt} - e^{-ibt}\big) \ dt \\
&= \frac{1}{2i} \int_{0}^{\infty}\big(e^{(-a+ib)t} - e^{(-a-ib)t}\big) \ dt
\end{align*}

... but now I'm unsure how to continue. Using my derived identity above the first integral term is simple, but the second term is causing me trouble. I tried applying a complementary identity involving a subtraction instead of an addition to the second term, however it did not appear to be simplifiable.

Any help or hints on how to proceed from here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: But you're almost there! Since $b$ is an arbitrary constant in the identity above, you may simply replace $b$ by $-b$ to get the expression for the second integral.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming $a>0$,
$$I(a,b)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-at}\sin(bt)\,dt = \text{Im}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-(a-ib)t}\,dt $$
hence
$$ I(a,b) = \text{Im}\left(\frac{1}{a-ib}\right) = \text{Im}\left(\frac{a+ib}{a^2+b^2}\right) = \color{red}{\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}}.$$

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't doubt it's correct, but to me it isn't entirely clear how to justify the second equality... I'm assuming it's some result of Euler's formula?

Comment: @EricHansen: $$ \text{Im} \int = \int \text{Im} $$ i.e. the imaginary part and the integral are two commuting linear operators.

Comment: Ah of course, I see it now, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

$\frac 1{2i}\int_{0}^{\infty}\big(e^{(-a+ib)t} - e^{(-a-ib)t}\big) \ dt\\
\int e^{(-a+ib)t} \ dt = \frac{(-a-ib)e^{(-a+ib)t}}{a^{2}+b^{2}}\\
\int e^{(-a-ib)t} \ dt = \frac{(-a+ib)e^{(-a-ib)t}}{a^{2}+b^{2}}$

$\dfrac 1{2i} \dfrac {-a(e^{(-a+ib)t}-e^{(-a-ib)t}) -ib(e^{(-a+ib)t}+e^{(-a-ib)t})}{a^2 + b^2}\\
\dfrac 1{2i} \dfrac {-a (e^{-at}) (2i \sin bt) - ib(e^{-at})(2\cos bt)}{a^2 + b^2}
\\
\dfrac {-e^{-at}(a\sin bt + b\cos bt)}{a^2 + b^2}\\$

That takes care of the integration.
Apply the limits.

$\dfrac {b}{a^2 + b^2}\\$

Comment: How is your third step (second integration) correct? Shouldn't you have $e^{(-a-ib)t}$?

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I fixed it by the next step!

Comment: Cheers, thanks. One further question - where does the negative symbol on $\frac{1}{2i}$ come from? I can't see where it was pulled.

Comment: That is probably me getting tired.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This approach makes sense to me now, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use parts twice, letting $$I = \int_0^\infty e^{-at}sin(bt)dt$$ with $u=e^{-at}$ and $dv=sin(bt)dt$ we have $$I=\frac{-1}{b}e^{-at}cos(bt)|_0^\infty - \frac{a}{b}\int_0^\infty e^{-at}cos(bt)dt. $$  The first term is $\frac{-1}{b}$ unless $a=0$ but in that case the integral is divergent.  Using parts once more with $u=e^{-at}$ and $dv=cos(bt)dt$ we have $$\frac{1}{b}-\frac{a}{b}[\frac{1}{b}sin(bt)e^{-at}|_0^\infty+\frac{a}{b}\int_0^\infty e^{-at}sin(bt)dt].$$  The second term is zero and we realize we have our original integral, I, back so we have, $$I = \frac{1}{b}-\frac{a^2}{b^2}I$$  Our integration  problem has been turned into a algebra problem, solving for I gives, $$I = \frac{b}{a^2+b^2}.$$